# Initializing Base Class: declaring a variable twice?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, declare

I'm currently reading trough a C# tutorial. Now I came across this:

```
using System;

namespace RectangleApplication {
   class Rectangle {

      //member variables
      protected double length;
      protected double width;

      public Rectangle(double l, double w) {
         length = l;
         width = w;
      }
      public double GetArea() {
         return length * width;
      }
      public void Display() {
         Console.WriteLine("Length: {0}", length);
         Console.WriteLine("Width: {0}", width);
         Console.WriteLine("Area: {0}", GetArea());
      }
   }//end class Rectangle  
   class Tabletop : Rectangle {
      private double cost;
      public Tabletop(double l, double w) : base(l, w) { }

      public double GetCost() {
         double cost;
         cost = GetArea() * 70;
         return cost;
      }
      public void Display() {
         base.Display();
         Console.WriteLine("Cost: {0}", GetCost());
      }
   }
   class ExecuteRectangle {
      static void Main(string[] args) {
         Tabletop t = new Tabletop(4.5, 7.5);
         t.Display();
         Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
}
```

In the `class Tabletop` there is `cost` declared twice. Once as `private double cost;` and 4 lines later as `double cost;`

> Why is that so?

When removing `double cost;` the Code still works. When `double cost` is in the code I can hover over `private double cost;` and read the message: The field `Tabletop.cost` is never used". I pretty much can remove either of the cost and the code works fine.

> 1. Did they forget to remove one of the declareation or is there a reason behind?
> 2. Also, why don't I get an error message like "cost is already defined"?

Here is the [Tutorial link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_inheritance.htm)

Comment: Voteup (+1) for they forgot to remove it. Both are unessary, could have just written `return GetArea() * 70;`

Comment: the cost from your method hides the member with the same name from your class. So effectivly you´re using the methods `cost` in the method, while outside the method you access the field. That´s why I prefer adding the (redundant) `this`-qualifier when I intent to use the field instead of the value of the method.

Comment: You don't get the error message because they're in different scopes.

Comment: Removing the local variable was a necessary fix. When you put it back, the field cost will always remain 0. Observable through Display().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`private double cost;` is unused and can be removed.

You don't get an error because as John said in the comments, it's in different scopes; one is defined as a field of the class while the other is a local variable. When `cost` is used, the local variable is accessed. To access the field, `this.cost` can be used.

```
class A
{
  private int a = 1;

  void A()
  {
    int a = 2;

    Console.WriteLine(a); // 2
    Console.WriteLine(this.a); // 1
  }
}
```

Note you cannot have multiple local variables with the same name, even in different scopes:

```
void A()
{
  int a = 1;

  if(someCondition)
  {
    int b = 2; // Compiler error: A local variable named 'a' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'a', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact, in your class `Tabletop`, the scopes `cost` is overlapped because there is also a local variable named `cost` in the method `GetCost`.

Within the scope of `GetCost`, when you refer to `cost`, you are actually referring to the locally scoped object named `cost` and not the one in the outer scope (the one in the class). When this happens, the `cost` declared in the outer scope is hidden by the inner scope(in the method).

Answer (score 1):

When defining a variable in a member-scope (in your case within a method) that has the same name as an existing member, you just hide the latter and reference the former.

So in your example:

```
class Tabletop : Rectangle 
{
    private double cost;
    public Tabletop(double l, double w) : base(l, w) { }

    public double GetCost() 
    {
        double cost;  // this hides the field
        cost = GetArea() * 70;
        return cost;  // this referts to the variable defined two lines above
    }
    public void Display() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cost: {0}", cost); // while this refers to the field
    }
}
```

`cost` from **within** `GetCost` will refer to the **local** variable, while using `cost` in `Display` for example will refer to the **field**.

This is absoluetely fine. However it can yield to confusion and thus unexpected behaviour. This is why some developers tend to use the `this`-qualifier:

```
public double GetCost() 
{
    double cost;
    this.cost = GetArea() * 70;
    return this.cost;
}
```

with the qualifier you refer to current instance, making `this.`cost` an access to your **field** instead of to the variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think they do forget to remove it.

As why you don't get "cost is already defined" error, it's because the `double cost` in `GetCost()` is local (only accessible inside `GetCost()` method, and will be destroyed from memory after `GetCost()` method completed), while the `private double cost` is available to the entire `Tabletop` class to be accessed and will be kept in memory as long as the `Tabletop` instance live.

Answer (score 0):

> In the class Tabletop there is cost declared twice. Once as private
>   double cost; and 4 lines later as double cost;

Well `private double cost;` is a member field for `tableTop` class whereas other declaration is local to the method body. Why there is a confusion.